# Custom controls in wxformbuilder

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder, wxtextctrl

I am currently having a issue with TextCtrlAutoComplete (https://wiki.wxpython.org/TextCtrlAutoComplete) and wxFormBuilder.

I would like to use the Autocomplete version but i have no way of telling wxFormbuilder to use a custom control as far as i can find.

How can i make it so it correctly generates the class. Or how to i correctly override the member in a subclass?

I also have problem with a workaround:

I have a few wxBoxsizers nested. I now have a TextCtrl as a place holder i would like to replace.

If i do :

```
self.m_textCtrlAlias = TextCtrlAutoComplete(self, [wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0], colSearch=True,choices=['example', 'hello', 'world', 'foo', 'bar'])
```

The control ends up in the upper left corner of the form. If there any way to replace the other control. I used wxBoxSizer in the master class there also not set as a member.

Anyone has more suggestions i am open to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I did: If the control is subclass of another control, say it is subclass of wxTextCtrl, then add wxTextCtrl using wxFormBuilder. Then set the subclass name of the wxTextCtrl to the class name of the control, in your case as I understand it is TextCtrlAutoComplete.

As you (Pimmetje) also have mentioned " *The header can be used to set the import for python.*"

Comment: Did u make a script do this or did u replace it in the generated code because that's something i would like to avoid.

Comment: Neither, it is done at the design phase of the interface with wxFormBuilder. The names will be automatically replaced in the generated code.

Comment: Where can u do that?

Comment: Found it (subclass->name) If i modify the autocomplete text control to accept the same parameters this might be a nice work around thanks. If i get it working ill accept your answer.

Comment: I got the code working. The only part that's not working is the import for the control. How do i get `from TextCtrlAutoComplete import TextCtrlAutoComplete` in the autogenerated code?

Comment: Other than the documents states; The header can be used to set the import for python. This will save me a lot of times. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. If u change your answer ill accept it.